# How to save index in array after filtering in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have array of objects in Angular JS.

For showing this array I use `ng-repeat` with filter by value from input field.

Problem is that when I typing text in field `ng-repeat` makes filtering and changes indexes of array.

Default array before filtering:

```
0 => obj(o)
1 => obj(b)
2 => obj(c)
```

If I type "b" I get output list:

```
0 => obj(b)
```

But with index `0`, if element is one.
So index `0` had `obj(o)` before filtering.

How I can save indexes that will be  `1 => obj(b)` after filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $scope.defaultArray = [
        0 => obj(o)
        1 => obj(b)
        2 => obj(c)
     ];
     $scope.filteredArray = $scope.defaultArray;
```

Use filteredArray variable in your ng-repeat
Then for every element remaining in filteredArray you can get its index
by doing this : $scope.defaultArray.indexOf(obj(b)) if I search "b"

Comment: What do you mean? Read please question again

Comment: Looks like a good answer to me. Maybe you need to provide your code.